# I want to create a "Go Back" Button using an image

Tags: html

This is the code that isn't working right now.

The "go back"-image is there, but it's not clickable for some reason.

```
<img src={{asset('img/icons/back.png')}} href="{{ route('users.index') }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

An `img` element doesn't work like a link. Wrap it with an `a` element.

```
<a href="{{ route('users.index') }}"><img src={{asset('img/icons/back.png')}} ></a>
```